# Converting string into the unsigned integer

Tags: c++, string, encoding, integer

I use the following code to convert the string into the integers:

```
int main(){
const char* mystring="abcdefghijklmnop";

unsigned int* key = (unsigned int*)mystring;
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
     std::cout << i << ": " << key[i] << std::endl;
}
std::cout << std::endl << "Result for:" << mystring << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
0: 1684234849
1: 1751606885
2: 1818978921
3: 1886350957

Result for:abcdefghijklmnop
```

As you can see, its working really fine, but just until the moment when the encoding is different, eg. for the string like: `®_ďÚ.J.®—Mf3Lý!®` (ASCII) (see the `Result for:` below)

```
It returns:

0: 3294604994
1: 781894543
2: 2931961418
3: 1301577954

Result for:Â®_ÄŹĂš.J.Â®â€”Mf3LĂ˝!Â® // <-- notice this, its totally different as the input (`®_ďÚ.J.®—Mf3Lý!®`)
```

I was trying setting the encoding in my IDE (Netbeans) but without any possitive results, also I was trying to compile to source on ideone.com, setting the browser encoding - unfortunately with the same results. Is there any possibility for it to generate the `real` result based on the input string encoding without messing it up? Maybe there are any other possibilities to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE is entering the characters encoded as UTF-8. I verified this by working backwards from your numeric output, it produced `®_ďÚ.J.®—M`. By the way, calling that ASCII is not accurate at all.

Your output window is using a different encoding. By the looks of it it's [code page 1250 Central/Eastern European](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250).

Comment: Yeah, you was almost right, the encoding was set to the UTF8 with BOM... solution is simple - set the encoding in each cpp file using fe. Notepad++ and compile it in Netbeans.